# Integrating Unity to Swift project with Push Extension using "jiulongw/swift-unity "

Tags: ios, swift, unity-game-engine

Good day!
I'm trying to integrate unity using [jiulongw/swift-unity](https://github.com/jiulongw/swift-unity) into my project, which has Notification Extension (OneSignal). When assembling, I get the following error:

```
<unknown>:0: error: error opening input file '/Volumes/DataDisk/TestOneSignal/IOSTemplate3OneSignal/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension/Unity/Bridging-Header.h' (No such file or directory)
<unknown>:0: error: cannot open file '/Users/vitaliykozlov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DemoProject-haxduxdlnjguxkcogcuqaymwlynv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/Bridging-Header-3KPPRZGOMOC4Z.dia' for diagnostics emission (No such file or directory)
Command PrecompileSwiftBridgingHeader failed with a nonzero exit code.
```

Although integration into a project without Notification Extension (OneSignal) works fine. I use the latest versions of Xcode and Unity. 
Please help the question is very important, I've tried everything !!!

Answer (score 0):

once i get this kinds of error may be this can help you

firs of all open your project in finder and give read,write,edit permission to this file  **Bridging-Header.h** then also give permission this file using terminal by `sudo chmod 777 /*path of yourfile */` or `chmod -R 777 foldername or pathname`